# Replace each value in Series with its relative ranking

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sorted Series, is there a simple way to change it from

```
A    0.064467
B    0.042283
C    0.037581
D    0.017410
dtype: float64
```

to

```
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried googling it?

Comment: Ah, I was looking at sort_values when I should have been looking at rank() as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `rank`

```
df.rank(ascending=False)
```